# Change all unique values in table with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have "table" with field "data". This "data" contains property "text" {text: 'some_string'}.

How to go through the table and concatenate all unique texts with 'another_string' using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Is your table like the following snippet code? 
```data: {
text: 'some_string'
}```

Comment: please clear your question with an example.

Comment: Yep, it's like 
`data: {items: [], text: ' ', smth_else: ' ', smth_else: ' '}`

I need to find only unique texts and add to them my "another_string"

Comment: Ok, try my answer, if doesn't solve your problem, notif to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data is:
`data = [ {text: "str1"}, {text: "str2"}, {text: "str1"} ]`
So, try the following snippet code:

```
uniq_str = ""

data.each do |d|
    uniq_str = uniq_str + d[:text].to_s unless uniq_str.include? d[:text].to_s
end

puts uniq_str    # str1str2
```

Comment: Thanks, but I guess, I did not explain structure well enough.

I have table with field data, so my aim is to change text in "data" field of table called "table" through all table elements. Hope it made a bit clearer

Comment: I mean, it looks like I need iterate in model "Table", not in "data" field.

Comment: ```Table.each do |d|
    uniq_str = uniq_str + d[:data][:text].to_s unless uniq_str.include? d[:data][:text]
end```